# How to allow limited special characters in regular expression validation only in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below asp.net c# Regular expression validation

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" TabIndex="0"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CausesValidation="true" Cssclass="state-error" SetFocusOnError="true" ID="valName" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic"
                    runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"  ErrorMessage="Name is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="error-state" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                    ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]*$" ErrorMessage="Special characters not allowed." />
```

Now I want that it should allow '-', '(', ')' characters only... Please help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as you require:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" TabIndex="0"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CausesValidation="true" Cssclass="state-error" SetFocusOnError="true" ID="valName" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic"
                runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"  ErrorMessage="Name is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator CssClass="error-state" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\s()\-]*$" ErrorMessage="Special characters not allowed." />
```